# Is it possible to remove logs in GraphDB?

Tags: graphdb, rdf4j

I have a GraphDB application with a huge folder size in "./logs".
I notice there are 3 types of file logs: error, main, and query.

I understand We can delete those but I could find any mention in the documentation. Is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely safe to delete the logs if you don't need them.